# How to Apply While Loop Condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Create procedure [dbo].[proc_Search_Username](@username varchar(25))
as 
  begin
    Declare @AccStatus int
    Set @AccStatus = 15

     while (@AccStatus = (select account_status from users where username like @username+'%'))
       begin
         select username from users where username like @username+'%'
       end
  end
```

In above Stored Procedure i want to get all users info.. whose `username` start with `"a"` at the same time i want to check they `account is active or inactive`  if account is `inactive` i dont want to display they information... Only `active user` info.

Comment: Your approach simple makes no sense.  Sample data and desired results would help clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this instead....

```
Create procedure [dbo].[proc_Search_Username](@username varchar(25))
as 
begin
    Declare @AccStatus int
    Set @AccStatus = 15;

         select username from users 
         where username like @username+'%'
         and account_status = @AccStatus
end
```

dont really see the reason why would you declare a variable for `@AccStatus` inside the procedure and then assign a value and then pass it to the query, simply pass the value to the query unless you are planning to pass this variable to the procedure. Then make it the procedure variables .

Comment: @Sri have a look at this [`How to accept an answer`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers)